# Why does Mathematica report the VertexEccentricity of a disconnected vertex as zero?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

["For a disconnected graph, all vertices are defined to have infinite eccentricity"](http://%20For%20a%20disconnected%20graph,%20all%20vertices%20are%20defined%20to%20have%20infinite%20eccentricity)

So, why does Mathematica report the VertexEccentricity of a disconnected vertex as 0 instead of `\[Infinity]`?

```
g = VertexAdd[Graph[{1 -> 2}], 3]; VertexEccentricity[g, 3]
```

Comment: I undeleted this question because it and its answer may be useful to others.  I cannot see why you would but if you have strong feelings about this and absolutely want it deleted **flag** the question and let me know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A nonstandard version of graph eccentricity for a given vertex v is implemented as VertexEccentricity[g, v], which gives the eccentricity for the connected component in which v is contained.

[**Ref**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphEccentricity.html)